# not working iframe opps

Tags: .htaccess, iframe

```
<#iframe src="http://www.turkiyewebservisi.com/reklam.html" runat="server" id="iframe1" width="500" height="500"><#/#iframe>
```

This is my code. When I add it to another site it does not work.

Comment: How does it not work? And do you have the # in the iframe tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that other site would have to support the `runat="server"` attribute. is that other site running on ASP.net?